# How long should I wait to turn on the water, after gluing my pipes together?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

The hot water line from my water heater to the house just came apart recently shooting water everywhere, so I re-glue the parts and wait a few hours and turn on the water. A few minutes later it blows off again. I replaced some parts today, primed and glued the pipes together and same thing happened again. I've waited about 3 hours both times this has happened, do you think I need to wait longer? It has been about 30 degrees as well.

Am I turning on the water supply too fast?

Comment: What kind of parts are you gluing together?  What sort of glue and you using.  Are you using any primer?  It should not be possible to turn the water on "too fast".  Instead, there is probably a problem with the materials used or techique, though possibly a problem with something else.

Comment: I have a 3/4" pvc pipe going into a [pvc pipe elbow](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/5e/5e4c47c5-29b0-4c2a-97f0-2507c5d36c60_300.jpg) and this is where it comes apart. I'm using primer and clear pvc cement similar to [this](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=28976496&cp=2568443.2568452.2631237.2631266.1260866)

Comment: Are they both SCH40?

Comment: 30 degrees F or C? rather different. Also - hot water in PVC pipe? (not CPVC pipe?)

Comment: Ecnerwal - it is Fahrenheit. It goes into a pvc pipe > elbow > cpvc.  


Chief Two Pencils - Not sure what SCH40 means, could you explain?

Comment: @Dusty580:  SCH40 means schedule 40, a system of rating pipe thicknesses.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_Pipe_Size#NPS_tables_for_selected_sizes).

Answer (score 2):

30 degrees Fahrenheit is **a bit cold** for happy PVC gluing, IMHO. You might want to apply some (non-open flame, given the solvents) heat to the joint before gluing and while it's curing. Also be absolutely sure that the pipe is dry, or else use the "damp-tolerant" PVC glue (usually blue.)

[A temperature range of 40-100 degrees F is recommended by the glue manufacturer](http://newsite.oatey.com/Channel/FAQ.html#Q03) They note that it is possible to get a strong joint below freezing, but that extended time is required. If you can safely heat it, do. 6 hour cure time is specified for your pipe size and temperature; that can be shortened to an hour above 60F (assuming water pressure is below 180 PSI....)

I do seriously question using PVC **at all** in hot water service - that's what CPVC is made for, and I have personally used hot water to bend PVC pipe. If you can borrow the tools from someone, I'd actually look into replacing as much of it as is easily accessible with PEX, these days.